# Thread main giving exception ---- error undefined in open refine

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, rdf, openrefine

I am running open refine 3.2 on windows 10 ,64 bit 
by unzipping the file and clicking either double-clicking or by cmd with "refine.bat".I have tried everything from environmental variables to RDF extensions compatibility .It is giving following and is stuck with localhost: **127.0.0.1:3333** with "**Butterfly still initializing**".I don't know what is this.Everything the helpers suggested I have tried.Please help me in running open refine I have a project to submit.
The cmd results are as follows:

```
23:09:00.024 [            refine_server] Starting Server bound to '127.0.0.1:3333' (0ms)
23:09:00.032 [            refine_server] Initializing context: '/' from 'C:\Program Files\openrefine-3.2\webapp' (8ms)
23:09:00.551 [            refine_server] Failed to use jdatapath to detect user data path: resorting to environment variables (519ms)
23:09:00.553 [            refine_server] Failed to use jdatapath to detect user data path: resorting to environment variables (2ms)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/openrefine-3.2/server/target/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.18.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/openrefine-3.2/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.18.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
23:09:00.712 [                   refine] Starting OpenRefine 3.2 [55c921b]... (159ms)
23:09:00.712 [                   refine] initializing FileProjectManager with dir (0ms)
23:09:00.712 [                   refine] C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\OpenRefine (0ms)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:351)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:302)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.reflect(JavaMembers.java:424)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.<init>(JavaMembers.java:43)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.lookupClass(JavaMembers.java:812)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.initMembers(NativeJavaClass.java:49)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:44)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.<init>(NativeJavaClass.java:43)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.<init>(NativeJavaClass.java:39)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrapJavaClass(WrapFactory.java:139)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:135)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:84)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2313)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1579)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1572)
        at 
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__Users_HP_AppData_Roaming_OpenRefine_extensions_freebase_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_12._c_init_1(file:/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/OpenRefine/extensions/freebase/module/MOD-INF/controller.js:46)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__Users_HP_AppData_Roaming_OpenRefine_extensions_freebase_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_12.call(file:/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/OpenRefine/extensions/freebase/module/MOD-INF/controller.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3508)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__Users_HP_AppData_Roaming_OpenRefine_extensions_freebase_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_12.call(file:/C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/OpenRefine/extensions/freebase/module/MOD-INF/controller.js)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.ButterflyModuleImpl.scriptInit(ButterflyModuleImpl.java:636)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.ButterflyModuleImpl.init(ButterflyModuleImpl.java:94)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.initializeModule(Butterfly.java:476)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.configure(Butterfly.java:451)
        at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.init(Butterfly.java:308)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at com.google.refine.RefineServer.configure(Refine.java:291)
        at com.google.refine.RefineServer.init(Refine.java:203)
        at com.google.refine.Refine.init(Refine.java:109)
        at com.google.refine.Refine.main(Refine.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: It is complaining about missing the org.json.JSONException class. You need to get the org.json [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107 ] file and put it on your classpath (Under C:/Program Files/openrefine-3.2/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ would be the best bet)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I donwloaded Openrefine 3.2 and can import RDF as expected without any exception and use the rdf-extension 3.2

Answer (score 1):

In OpenRefine, this error is often caused by incompatible extensions being installed.

Check the folder where extensions are stored
(`C:/Documents and Settings/Application Data/OpenRefine` OR `C:/Documents and Settings/Local Settings/Application Data/OpenRefine` normally)

Remove the extensions installed (by deleting the files in that directory) and try starting OpenRefine again.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException` - for me it's obvious what's the problem ... and yes, it could very well be an issue with mixed version and extensions.

Comment: @sheprogrm it maybe worth checking the actual OpenRefine folder itself as extensions can also be directly installed in there. If you open the folder where OpenRefine is installed and navigate to the "extensions" folder (I think either in the main folder, or in a subfolder called 'webapp') and check the content there - this should be: database; gdata; jython; pc-axis; phonetic; sample; wikidata. If there are any other extensions in there, delete them